# How to make each element of multiple lists appear on DataGrid in a single line

Tags: c#, selenium, uwp-xaml

I have a web crawler that takes data from an airlines website.

And I want the program to display each of the elements in their respective lines.

```
            foreach (string url in urlList)
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

                try
                {
                    var DepAirport = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//td[@class='depdest']/div[@class='content']").ToList();
                    var ArrAirport = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//td[@class='arrdest']/div[@class='content']").ToList();
                    var DepTime = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//td[@class='depdest']/div[@class='content emphasize']").ToList();
                    var ArrTime = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//td[@class='arrdest']/div[@class='content emphasize']").ToList();
                    var Price = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//td[@class='fareselect standardlowfare']/div[@class='content']/label[@class='label seatsokfare']").ToList();

                    foreach(var da in DepAirport)
                    {                 
                        _entries.Add(new EntryModel { DepartureAirport = da.Text });
                    }
                    foreach (var aa in ArrAirport)
                    {
                        _entries.Add(new EntryModel { ArrivalAirport = aa.Text });
                    }
                    foreach (var dt in DepTime)
                    {
                        _entries.Add(new EntryModel { DepartureTime = dt.Text });
                    }
                    foreach (var at in ArrTime)
                    {
                        _entries.Add(new EntryModel { ArrivalTime = at.Text });
                    }
                    foreach (var p in Price)
                    {
                        _entries.Add(new EntryModel { Price = p.Text });
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
```

It collects the data and displays it on the Grid, however the results look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all `EntryModel` properties. Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < DepAirport.Count; i++)
{
    _entries.Add(new EntryModel
    {
        DepartureAirport = DepAirport[i].Text,
        ArrivalAirport = ArrAirport[i].Text,
        DepartureTime = DepTime[i].Text,
        ArrivalTime = ArrTime[i].Text,
        Price = Price[i].Text
    });
}
```

The problem is that every call to `_entries.Add(..` creates a new entry and, therefore, a new row. But, each row has only one property set.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT . Okay, so there is another problem, if DepAirport.Count is more than one, lets say 2. When the loop should go a second time, it throws an exception "system.argumentoutofrangeexception".

Comment: if you have another problem please feel free post the new thread in so.